# Multiple "Undefined reference" errors with MXE and SDL2

Tags: c, mingw, cross-compiling, sdl-2, mxe

I am trying to compile a OpenGL program which uses SDL for context creation and image loading. When I compile it on Linux natively, it compiles and runs without error. I have installed MXE in /opt/mxe and have checked that the SDL2 directory (which contains headers) is in `/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/` while the corresponding libraries (`libSDL.a`, etc.) are in `/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/`.

The included header files are `<SDL2/SDL.h>` and `<SDL2/SDL_image.h>`

I am trying to compile the said program using

`i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc 5_transformation.c -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include -L/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lGLEW -lopengl32 -lm -mwindows`

However, it gives multiple undefined reference errors: [http://pastebin.com/JaadTNnv

][1](http://pastebin.com/JaadTNnv)

Many of these errors seem related to Direct3D and such, which I am not using (but SDL2 might, internally). Do I have to link against them too? Am I even doing this right? (MXE page doesn't seems to have any detailed instructions).

PS. This question, or it's variants, seem to be pretty popular across internet. However, I have already followed their instructions. My main function is defined as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, I am linking against -lmingw32, -lSDL2main and -mwindows, I have made sure that the path in GCC's arguments are correct, I tried  putting `i686-w64-mingw32.static-sdl-config --cflags --libs` and `i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config SDL_image --cflags --libs`
in arguments instead of explicit linking (that simply gave undefined reference for SDL functions like `SDL_GL_CreateContext` and `IMG_Load` and said that `Package SDL_image was not found in the pkg-config search path.`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed MXE in `/opt/mxe/` and the following worked for me (the file I was trying to compile was `5_transformation.c`):

```
/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc 5_transformation.c -mwindows `/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --cflags sdl2` `/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --cflags SDL2_image` -lmingw32 -lGLEW -lopengl32 -lm `/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --libs sdl2` `/opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --libs SDL2_image`
```

Make sure to get the path to all executables correct (`gcc` as well as `pkg-config`), put the `--cflags` argument before `--libs` one, make sure that you types `sdl2` (sdl in small case) and `SDL2_image` (SDL in caps), use `-mwindows`, `-lmingw32` and use `-lopengl32` instead of `-lgl`

Answer (score 1):

You should use **pkg-config --cflags sdl2** and **pkg-config --libs sdl2** to get all the cflags and libs you need. (Btw. don't include *SDL2/SDL.h* but only *SDL.h* and use the *pkg-config --cflags* values to set up your include paths if you want to be more portable)

Instead of using *pkg-config*, you can also use *sdl2-config*

If this also doesn't help in your setup - then check out the sdl2 example that is delivered with mxe. Add your code to it, and try to (re-)compile sdl2 in mxe by running *make sdl2* in your mxe checkout. (https://github.com/mxe/mxe/commit/c3624cdefb7ff0c4b69316c7c1b740b97f55e1db)

Comment: I had to play around with paths and order a bit, but pkg-config did worked at last (sdl-config still didn't, for some reason)